# Bootstrap 3 buttons borders overlap when resized

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    ...
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
           ...
           <div class="btn-group" role="group">
              <button type="button" class="read-more" data-goto="more">READ MORE</button>
              <button type="button" class="read-more" data-goto="quote">FREE QUOTE</button>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

**This is how it looks on full screen:**

[image]

**This is how it looks when resized:**

[image]

My problem is the little border overlap, is there a way there can be a little bit of margin right above FREE QUOTE button or right below READ MORE button? I dont want to add css margin-top or margin-bottom to these buttons because it will affect the way they look on full screen. Maybe there is a trick that I am missing.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Run the updated code snippet, its tested & works perfectly. Hope thats helps.

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        background-color: blue !important;
    }
  
  .read-more{
    margin-bottom:3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    ...
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-lg-8">
           ...
           <div class="btn-group" role="group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md read-more" data-goto="more">READ MORE</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md read-more" data-goto="quote">FREE QUOTE</button>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Run the following code snippet 100% working & tested.

Hope it helps.

Comment: wont that also affect the original full width layout?

Comment: is the above output for Medium Resolution / Small Resolution?

Comment: You need to search the class in your bootstrap css "read-more" under that particular media query & update the css as shown above.

Comment: The overlap happens only when resized to small resolution, if i add margin it will also apply that to full width

Comment: Or another work around is to simply add another css in that particular media query manually rather than searching all over.

Comment: Search the small resolution media query code in  css & update your code as above thats all.

Comment: Ref link to media query: https://scotch.io/tutorials/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries